# Change dual boot Ubuntu to Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, windows-10

i have an Ubuntu system dual booted with Windows10. I want to change Ubuntu with Lubuntu (i don't care about my Ubuntu files), so here is my question: if a launch Lubuntu installer from USB then i erase Ubuntu partition and use empty space to install Lubuntu, would it work without some boot problem? I don't want to have troubles with Grub, that is pretty annoying with dual boot. I try to google for it but i didn't find anything. Any good / bad experience with this?

Comment: You could do what you are proposing, although I think that you will still need to deal with grub.  Alternatively, you could `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @CharlesGreen's second proposal installs Lubuntu's desktop environment LXDE and all of its standard applications to your current Ubuntu installation. It does not remove your current Unity (?) desktop environment and applications. As a consequence, you will be able to decide which desktop to load on each login. Sometimes there can be issues with having multiple desktop environments installed, but Unity and LXDE are rather compatible in my experience, so you should be fine. Manually removing Unity after installing LXDE is not easy though, if you want that you should reinstall the system.

Comment: @CharlesGreen oh, thanks, great command, but i also would to clean my installation, so run the command and then clean all the garbage i have installed would have the same effect as install lubuntu from scratch, right?

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks for advice, but i want the system to be faster and lighter, so i don't want to take my (i think) Unity desktop, i don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Lubuntu the same way you installed Ubuntu by booting from a bootable USB or disk.

When it comes to the partitioning section, choose "Something Else".

Check off your Ubuntu partitions to be used as root (`/`) as well as any other partitions you used previously such as `/home` and swap.  Check the boxes to format the old Ubuntu partitions.  If you had a separate partition for your `/home` directory, you can leave it intact to access your files and reuse by not formatting it, or format it as well, that is up to you.

Choose to install grub on your boot drive, selecting the drive itself and not a particular partitions, IE `/dev/sda` not `/dev/sda1`.  Continue with the installation as per normal install.

You *can* simply install Lubuntu desktop, however, this takes more drive space, and leave many Ubuntu apps on your system.  Since you don't care about the Ubuntu files, it's best to wipe the partitions and reinstall with a clean system.

Comment: Do you know if this kind of installation could cause trobles with Grub? I mean, could it stop detecting Windows installation or stop work at all?

Comment: @Prasqui No.  When you reinstall grub during the install, it will overwrite it.  When it does that, it will detect your Windows 10 installation and add it to the boot menu automatically.  After your installation, you'll be able to choose Lubuntu or Windows 10 when you boot up.

Comment: Nice, really thanks you. I'm not yet so comfortable with Linux system, and sometimes i'm really scared by trying things before knowing exactly what will happen.
PS: i also upvoted your question, but i'm too low in reputation to make this be visible.